# SlideToggle open only one container at a time Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, slidetoggle

Maybe someone know how to open only one container at a time? Now in this example you can open all three? I would like to open only one and when it's opened change text to "Close". Any ideas?

Here is the link with a code to codepen: `code` https://codepen.io/jorgemaiden/pen/YgGZMg

I'll be really apreciate for any help and tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in many ways, but according to your reference, I would just add function that loop through your elements which is not your clicked element, then remove active class if it's present

```js
var linkToggle = document.querySelectorAll(".js-toggle");

for (i = 0; i < linkToggle.length; i++) {
  linkToggle[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var container = document.getElementById(this.dataset.container);
    this.innerText = "Close";
    toggleSlide(container);
  });
}

function toggleSlide(container) {
  for (i = 0; i < linkToggle.length; i++) {
    let el = document.getElementById(linkToggle[i].dataset.container);
    if (el != container && el.classList.contains("active")) {
      el.style.height = "0px";
      linkToggle[i].innerText = "Click";
      el.addEventListener(
        "transitionend",
        function() {
          el.classList.remove("active");
        }, {
          once: true
        }
      );
    }
  }
  if (!container.classList.contains("active")) {
    container.classList.add("active");
    container.style.height = "auto";

    var height = container.clientHeight + "px";

    container.style.height = "0px";

    setTimeout(function() {
      container.style.height = height;
    }, 0);
  } else {
    container.style.height = "0px";

    container.addEventListener(
      "transitionend",
      function() {
        container.classList.remove("active");
      }, {
        once: true
      }
    );
  }
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle-container {
  transition: height 0.35s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.toggle-container:not(.active) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="js-toggle" data-container="toggle-1">Click</div>
  <div class="toggle-container" id="toggle-1">I have an accordion and am animating the the height for a show reveal - the issue is the height which i need to set to auto as the information is different lengths.<br><br> I have an accordion and am animating the the height fferent lengths.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div class="js-toggle active" data-container="toggle-2">Click</div>
  <div class="toggle-container open" id="toggle-2">I have an accordion and am animating the the height for a show reveal - the issue is the height which i need to set to auto as the information is different lengths.<br><br> I have an accordion and am animating the the height fferent lengths.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div class="js-toggle" data-container="toggle-3">Click</div>
  <div class="toggle-container" id="toggle-3">I have an accordion and am animating the the height for a show reveal - the issue is the height which i need to set to auto as the information is different lengths.<br><br> I have an accordion and am animating the the height fferent lengths.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you! I'll study your suggestion! :)

Comment: @Get_Date no prob, just ask if you get stuck

Comment: Hi aleng, one more quick question.  Now I have 4 flex columns per row, and when you click on any "find out more" button from first row, full width container slides out below second row. How I could I achieve that, if I press on "find out more" on any column from first row container slides out exactly below that container in full width and if you press on any button on second row, container will slide out below second row? Here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/dzestis94/pen/xxPByRg .

Comment: @Get_Date you should change the layout, make div wrapper for row, as per your example, you will have two rows div, that contain 4 flex columns. then have your "toggle-container" placed inside their respective wrapper. If you want me to show in code, consider opening a new question